# Why can ci" be outside of quoted area and ci( only works inside parentheses?

Tags: cursor-motions, cursor-movement

When using <kbd>ci"</kbd> the cursor does not have to reside in the double quoted area.

```
|String somestring = "some text";
```

Assuming the pipe is the cursor position, <kbd>ci"</kbd> will make it jump to the quoted area.

On the other hand, when using <kbd>ci(</kbd>, the cursor must be inside the parentheses to work and will not move the cursor inside them.

What is the reason for this difference in behavior?
I assume there is a way to map the keys so that this behavior is present. Are there any drawbacks to doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650788/why-ci-and-ci-ci-behave-differently

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The main difference here is that parenthetical statements (targeted by `ci(`) can be nested, while quoted strings (targeted by `ci"`) cannot.

If your cursor is outside of some parenthetical statement, it could still be inside of some other one. For example (`*` marks the cursor position):

```
$foo = array(
    'x' => ar*ray(1, 2, 3),
);
```

The line the cursor is on contains `(1, 2, 3)`, but the cursor is also inside the larger `array(...)` block. In this case, the larger one is the appropriate target for `ci(`.

If your cursor is outside of some quoted string, since they can't be nested, there's no perfectly sensible thing to do. So, Vim takes advantage and finds the first quoted string on the line.

Answer (score 10):

The quote family of text objects (`i'`, `i"`, `a'`, and `a"`) are different than the rest of the text objects in that they only look at the current line.  Due to this, the choice was made not to require the cursor to be within the quotes.  Instead, Vim will search forward within the line to find a quoted string when the cursor isn't already inside one.

There is a [discussion](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/43570) around some patches which would allow this forward searching behavior to be implemented for block based text objects as well.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers covered *why* this happens. Here's a nice way to work around it.

[wellle/targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim). I just recently found this plugin, and I think it's extremely underrated. It provides a new text object: `din(` Mnemonic: (d)elete (i)nside (n)ext "(". This is compatible with other operators and several different objects, such as `an(`, `in"`, `il(` (inside last parenthesis)

It also overrides the default behavior of `i(` so that it first looks to see if the cursor is in parentheses, and then if it isn't it works the same way as `in(`. This behavior can be turned on or off. For example:

```
def foo(bar):
^cursor here
```

Typing `ci(` acts the same as `cin(`, since the cursor is not in parentheses.

```
def foo( ):
        ^Cursor here, and in insert mode
```

This also accepts a count:

```
def foo(bar):           #Define function foo(bar)
^cursor here
```

Typing `c2in(`:

```
def foo(bar):           #Define function foo( )
                                             ^cursor here
```

This also provides a new object, "argument". For example, `dana` means "Delete around the next argument". This also accepts a count. For example:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, BADarg3):
^ cursor here
```

Typing `d3ana`:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
                  ^ cursor here
```

There are *many* other features this plugin has, but these are the basic ones.

Comment: Nice! This is a good addition. I might have to check that out.

Comment: Great answer 10/10 but I gotta give it a 9/10 because examples are python

Answer (score 1):

James mentioned a powerful plugin for this. I also made one that's much much simpler which just extends ci" to use ), }, ], <, which works with the cursor anywhere on the current line: https://github.com/Spenny1068/ciBracket