# ci[ ; bracket recognition fails

Tags: cursor-motions, neovim

i have the following Text in my vim ('|' is my cursor.:

```
"|--------------[ LatexBox ]-------------
```

When i press `ci[`, nothing happens. I would expect that it doesn't matter where exactly in the line my cursor is. at least when a pair of brackets in the line is.

```
"--------------[| LatexBox ]-------------
```

Now, when i press `ci[` nvim delets the content of the Brackets and puts me in insert mode, as expected.

**=> How can i fix that?**

PS: I know [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/19/2354) question, but in this example i don't have multiple brackets.

**EDIT:** Btw. that example doesn't work also in a single buffer without any other content (suggested also in [1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/19/2354))

Comment: The behavior you describe works for strings, but not brackets, and there are good reasons. See [my answer on a related question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/33/64).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is the expected behavior of `ci[` (and `ci(`, and `ci{`). There is *nothing* to "fix", here.

But you can use [this script](https://gist.github.com/sjl/1171642) to add your desired behavior to Vim:

```
" Motion for "next/last object". For example, "din(" would go to the next "()" pair
" and delete its contents.

onoremap an :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 'f')<cr>
xnoremap an :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 'f')<cr>
onoremap in :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 'f')<cr>
xnoremap in :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 'f')<cr>

onoremap al :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 'F')<cr>
xnoremap al :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 'F')<cr>
onoremap il :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 'F')<cr>
xnoremap il :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 'F')<cr>

function! s:NextTextObject(motion, dir)
  let c = nr2char(getchar())

  if c ==# "b"
      let c = "("
  elseif c ==# "B"
      let c = "{"
  elseif c ==# "d"
      let c = "["
  endif

  exe "normal! ".a:dir.c."v".a:motion.c
endfunction
```