# Command to delete inside parentheses doesn't work

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Let's say I have a line of code:

```
for i in range(1, 100):
```

My cursor is on the `f` in `for`, and I want to delete the text inside the parenthesis. In other words, I want my line to look like this:

```
for i in range():
```

Where my cursor is on the second parenthesis. My initial instinct, after reading [this post](https://danielmiessler.com/study/vim/), was to type `di(` (see "A text object reference"). However, this does nothing. 
I also tried `dib` as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405415/can-you-grab-or-delete-between-parentheses-in-vi-vim) (see second answer), but again, nothing happened. What should I do to delete the text between the two parentheses?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is [expected behavior](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19/why-does-ci-and-ci-behave-differently), although it is definitely a little bit unintuitive. Really, the only good solution is `f(di(`.

Comment: You could use an `omap`, for example `:onoremap n( :<c-u>normal! f(vi(<cr>` then `dn(` will delete the text between the parentheses (and `cn(` will change the text, and `yn(` will yank the text, and so on).