# Automatically jump to text object during `ci(`

Tags: cursor-motions, object-motions

Suppose my cursor is at the beginning of the line of code:

`def f(a, b, c, d, e):`

If I want to change inside the parenthesis using the text object command `ci(`, I need to first navigate to some position in the parenthesis.

I would like it if I could just jump to the first relevant text object after my cursor when I type `ci(` (and analogous commands). How would I configure vim to do this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate but [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/19/1841) is strongly related because it explains why `ci(` and `ci"` behave differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`wellle/targets.vim` plugin](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) should do what you're looking for (and much more). This allows you to explicitly tell vim to go to the next parenthesis (with `cin(`, **n** for *next parenthesis*), or the last parenthesis (with `cil(`), but it also overrides the default so that you jump to the next or last if you don't specify. From the README:

> - This overrides Vim's default text object to allow seeking for the next pair in the current line to the right or left when the cursor is not inside a pair. This behavior is similar to Vim's seeking behavior of `di'` when not inside of quotes, but it works both ways.
>
> ...
>
> Next and Last Pair
>
> ```
> in( an( In( An( il( al( Il( Al( ...
> ```
>
> Work directly on distant pairs without moving there separately.
>
> All the above pair text objects can be shifted to the next pair by including the letter n. The command in) selects inside of the next pair. Use the letter l instead to work on the previous (last) pair. Uses a count to skip multiple pairs. Skipping works over multiple lines.
>
> See our Cheat Sheet for two charts summarizing all pair mappings.

This also adds the "argument" text object. For example, `dana` to delete the next argument. And many other text objects as well.